# Prove that $\min_{X \subseteq U} f(x) = \min_{X \subseteq U} g(x)$

Tags: functions, optimization

Let $U$ be a set. Consider funcions $f$ and $g$ that return positives values and nulls values (equal at zero). If $f(Z) \le g(Z)$ for all $Z \subseteq U$. Moreover, we know that exists $X' \subseteq U$ such that $f(X') = g(X')$. Show that $\min_{X \subseteq U} f(X) = \min_{X \subseteq U} g(X)$.

Proof. Since $f(Z) \le g(Z)$ for each $Z \subseteq U$, then
$$\min_{X \subseteq U} f(X) \le \min_{X \subseteq U} g(X)$$

How to show that $\min_{X \subseteq U} f(X) \ge \min_{X \subseteq U} g(X)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think you are a bit mixing the question and the solution you are provided somewhere. I would recommend isolating the problem statement and then ask your question.

Comment: The functions $f$ and $g$ can be defined as mapping of $2^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $U$ be a set. Consider funcions $f$ and $g$ that return positives
> values and nulls values (equal at zero). If $f(Z) \le g(Z)$ for all $Z
> > \subseteq U$. Moreover, we know that exists $X' \subseteq U$ such that
> $f(X') = g(X')$. Show that $\min_{X \subseteq U} f(X) = \min_{X
> > \subseteq U} g(X)$.

Not true. Counter-example below.

Choose $U = \{1, 2\}$ and

- $f(Z) = 1$ if $Z = \{1\}$ and $f(Z) = 2$ otherwise.
- $g(Z) = 2$ for any $Z\subseteq U$.